# Choosing probability threshold of logistic model predictions to obtain a certain specificity

Tags: r, classification, probability, logistic-regression, prediction

I've got a logistic prediction model which produced, for each person, a probability of being a case. Model AUC is 0.95.

Is there a way to determine the probability *threshold* that would give me 0.9 specificity? (Or any other arbitrarily specified level of specificity or sensitivity.) Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empirical values of sensitivity and specificity are of course data-set dependent. You can try extracting the class probability predicted by the logistic model using `predict` and setting different thresholds to calibrate it against specificity, but keep in mind that for your specificity figures to remain accurate on test data, the proportions of the classes have to be similarly distributed in training and test populations. In the example below, I created a function to map training data specificity to logistic model probability response thresholds for a simulated dataset.

```
set.seed(100)
x = rnorm(1000)
y = sapply(x, function(zeta) rbinom(1, 1, plogis(zeta)))
data <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
logistic_model <- glm(data = data, formula = y ~ 0 + x, family = "binomial")
summary(logistic_model)

# Call:
#   glm(formula = y ~ 0 + x, family = "binomial", data = data)
# 
# Deviance Residuals: 
#   Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
# -2.4626  -0.9187   0.5383   1.0284   2.3236  
# 
# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# x  1.09347    0.08576   12.75   <2e-16 ***
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
# 
# Null deviance: 1386.3  on 1000  degrees of freedom
# Residual deviance: 1163.2  on  999  degrees of freedom
# AIC: 1165.2
# 
# Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4


data$response <- predict(logistic_model, type = "response")
p_vals = seq(0,1,0.001)
specificity <- sapply(p_vals, function(p) sum(data$y == 0 & data$response < p)/sum(data$y == 0))
plot(p_vals, specificity, type = "l")

threshold_by_specificity <- function(spc)
  return(p_vals[sum(specificity <= spc)])

threshold_by_specificity(0.1)
##0.13
threshold_by_specificity(0.3)
##0.251
```

P.S. I am quite sure there is a function to do this in the `caret` package, but I couldn't find it.

P.P.S. As an aside, the logistic model specifies a probability distribution for the class given the feature vector, and obtaining theoretical values for sensitivity and/or specificity would involve the opposite, that is, a model that specifies a distribution for the feature vector given the class. To obtain this from the logistic model you'd need to assume a prior distribution for the data (or fit one to it). Without more details, it's not apparent how you should go about doing that, or if it is even needed.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem with code completion. Make one error and you repeat it all over the code. No longer does the compiler act as spell check.

Comment: Teaching computers to think has been a dream for a long time.

Comment: Thank you @ritwik33, as you can tell I'm pretty new to this. Yes I  meant spec/sens applied to a specific training set. Does it seem a reasonable idea to CV/bootstrap this process?

Comment: @bobmcpop Well, you could use cross validation on the estimate of specificity: compute specificity on the fold (partition) of the training data which you have not used to fit the logistic model, and then average over these values by leaving out a different fold while training each time. You could also do something like Out-of-bag samples, that is, you try taking bootstrap samples of the data with replacement, and calculate specificity using training observations not included in the sample, and then average over several bootstrap samples. I'm not sure either idea is theoretically sound, though.